# Error in alex-bond/yii2-thumbler "Class 'Thumbler' not found"

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

How to use this widget alex-bond/yii2-thumbler [Link](https://github.com/Alex-Bond/yii2-thumbler). i tried something like this

```
$path = \Yii::$app->thumbler->resize
        ('49_long.jpg',500,500, $method = Thumbler::METHOD_CROP_CENTER, $backgroundColor = 'ffffff', $callExceptionOnError = true);
```

as said there, but I got a error "Class 'Thumbler' not found". How can I use it?

Comment: Also note that you pass parameters as it declared in method, with default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding  add the correct reference to your code

```
 use alexBond\thumbler\Thumbler;
```